# On window close hook for play 2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to destroy user session once the user closes the window. Is there a hook available for on window close? I went through the documentation & found onStop() method in GlobalSettings but it seems that it is invoked when the server is closed. I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Play is a stateless framework, therefore a user 'session' is actually just a cookie. There is no server side session state. [See here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash)

The Play session cookie has Session expiry by default, so if the user closes their browser window (not tab) then a new cookie (or session) will be created next time.

If you want to remove the Play session cookie on tab close then [one of these options](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=javascript+on+window+close+clear+cookies&oq=javascript+on+window+close+clear+cookies&aqs=chrome..69i57.9114j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) will probably work for you.

Note: a browser window closing event is something you should handle client side, not server side.